# How to send a string from android to linux

Tags: android, sockets, netcat

I am trying to send a simple text from my android app to a server running on my laptop but even though I went through all the stuff I found on the internet I couldn't get it working. So this is the code on my android app:

```
public class Client extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
String dstAddress = "89.101.42.238";
int dstPort;
String response = "";
TextView status;

Client(String addr, int port, TextView textResponse) {
    dstAddress = addr;
    dstPort = port;
    this.status = textResponse;
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

    Socket socket = null;

    try {
        socket = new Socket("89.101.42.238", 5000);
        PrintStream printer = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        //BufferedWriter cout = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));

        printer.write("Salut!".getBytes());
        printer.write("Please work!!!!!!".getBytes());
        //status.setText("Finished");
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        response = "UnknownHostException: " + e.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        response = "IOException: " + e.toString();
    } finally {
        if (socket != null) {
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
}
}
```

On my laptop I run netcat listening on the port. The ip is my laptop's IP on icanhazip.com. Both my laptop and my phone are connected to a wi-fi network.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean with your laptops IP on icanhazip.com? You should use the local LAN ip of your laptop.

Comment: And what is netcat telling ypu?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending TCP data from Android (as client) - no data being sent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309201/sending-tcp-data-from-android-as-client-no-data-being-sent)

Comment: No it's not duplicated, my problem was other